# PayPal Billing Agreements with PHP in 2023

Tags: php, paypal

How can I use PayPal Billig Agreements with PHP in 2023? A Billing Agreement is different from subscriptions billing as the amount to be charged and time of payment are not fixed.

Currently we still use the [PayPal PHP Merchant SDK](https://github.com/paypal/merchant-sdk-php) which still works but is deprecated, 6 years old and does not work with current newer php versions.

The current PayPal REST APIs also has the [following deprecation notice](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments.billing-agreements/v1/):
*The /v1/payments/billing-agreements endpoints are deprecated*

How it is done in 2023?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Billing agreements is old API terminology. The general terms for this type of non-subscriptions billing are reference transactions, future payments, vault, and payment tokens. All of which mean approximately the same thing.

If the PayPal business account is approved for reference transactions, any of the API solutions will work. v2 and v3 vault are the newest ones, only PayPal can advise you on which one to use. There will be no SDK.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. There is a v3? I can't find it.

Comment: There is this beta document https://developer.paypal.com/beta/vault/purchase-later/paypal/

Comment: Do you know where to find the v2 documentation for reference transactions? The `https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments.billing-agreements/v1/? is deprecated. And I can't find anything to reference transactions without subscriptions.

Comment: newer than v1 billing agreements is the v2 or v3 vault

Comment: Thanks! Sorry, but I can't find it within https://developer.paypal.com/api/rest/ Do you have a link?